# Swapped images in xcode and now app is crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I deleted old images in xcode project, default.png, default@2x.png, etc., replaced them all with new images with the SAME SIZE and the SAME NAME - app build succeeded but crashed when opened (didn't go beyond hang screen using testflight)

Git Hard Reset and redeployed - app worked

Changed Images again - app build succeeded but crashed when opened (didn't go beyond hang screen using testflight)

Put back old images manually without reset - app build succeeded but crashed when opened (didn't go beyond hang screen using testflight)

Clearly this is not about the new images because I put them back. No clue what is happening. Not even sure what to google here.

Edit: Sorry, I am very new to this, but I see this at the bottom:
2013-11-07 22:41:17.651 MySaleTable[1934:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle  (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d52bf53 0x378556af 0x30146d41 0x2ff15b49 0x2fd07c25 0x2fca26a7 0x2fca19a9 0x2fd074fd 0x3213970d 0x321392f7 0x2d4f69e7 0x2d4f6983 0x2d4f5157 0x2d45fce7 0x2d45facb 0x2fd06799 0x2fd01a41 0x2eb45 0x37d5dab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you delete the derived data in the Xcode organizer, close and reopen Xcode. Then open the right pane file browser, and one by one seclect your storyboards and images in the left pane, and verify that it's included in the project. Select your storyboard and verify it loads in the center pane. You can also select the target and insure images and storyboards are in the Copy ToBundle phase (I forget exact name).

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that I had to go add the files separately in the folder (separate from the workspace project). Then check Build Phases and add and delete appropriate images. I am not sure if clearing derived data helped, but I did do that. Thanks.